# How check whether instance of impala daemon and instance of statestored deamon is running?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, impala

Like when you start hadoop or hbase. you can use jps to check whether namenode, tasktracker or jobtracker is running. Is there any command by which you can check impala deamons running or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command: `ps -ef | grep -i impalad`.

Comment: There's another Impala daemon called "statestored"; for more information, see http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_concepts.html#intro_statestore_unique_1